# Titulo gráfico de barras no ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

Fiz este gráfico com `geom_bar()`, gostaria que o título `(a)` seguisse a direção do `ylab`, mas não estou conseguindo.

Usei este parâmetro da função `geom_bar()`

```
theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0, size = 13))
```

consigo este resultado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

gostaria que o título ficasse alinhado ao `ylab`, da seguinte forma:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como proceder? usando o `hjust = 0`, esperava que o titulo já alinhasse com a margem do `ylab`, porém não acontece, tentei valores negativos também e não consegui.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Os valores de `hjust` podem ser negativos para você fazer o que precisa.

Por exemplo:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(iris, aes(x = Species)) +
  geom_bar() +
  ggtitle("Titulo") + 
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = -0.07, size = 13))
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Mito simples, obrigado.